# Issues in getting large files from s3 bucket to AWS Lambda

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda

I have a lambda function that gets the file from s3 on event of s3 bucket upload and then store it to tmp folder. It works on small files but not on files larger than 15mb. I have tried increasing memory, ephemeral storage and timeout but none worked. I also tried downloading in chunks. Here is the code I used.

```
const fs = require('fs');
const path = require('path');

const s3 = new AWS.S3();

exports.handler = async (event) => {
  const s3Params = {
    Bucket: event.Records[0].s3.bucket.name,
    Key: decodeURIComponent(event.Records[0].s3.object.key.replace(/\+/g, ' '))
  };
  
  const tempFilePath = path.join('/tmp', s3Params.Key);
  const fileSize = (await s3.headObject(s3Params).promise()).ContentLength;
  const chunkSize = 1024 * 1024; // 1 MB chunks
  
  for (let i = 0; i < fileSize; i += chunkSize) {
    const rangeEnd = Math.min(i + chunkSize - 1, fileSize - 1);
    const range = `bytes=${i}-${rangeEnd}`;
    const chunkParams = {
      ...s3Params,
      Range: range,
    };
    const { Body } = await s3.getObject(chunkParams).promise();
    if (i === 0) {
      fs.writeFileSync(tempFilePath, Body);
    } else {
      fs.appendFileSync(tempFilePath, Body);
    }
  }
  
  console.log(`File downloaded to ${tempFilePath}`);
  console.log("File size is " + fs.statSync(tempFilePath).size );
  
  fs.unlink(tempFilePath, (err) => {
    if (err) 
        throw err;
    console.log('deleted successfully');
});
};
```

It does not show up on cloud watch stream logs so I don't know what causes the issue. This is the screenshot of the latest logs that showed up, the file that was transferred is 15mb.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6LbkG.png)

Comment: What do you mean by "It does not show up on cloud watch stream logs"? Does _anything_ show in CloudWatch Logs? If not, make sure that the IAM Role associated with the function has the `AWSLambdaBasicExecutionRole` policy assigned.

Comment: @JohnRotenstein when working with files 15mb or smaller it shows in CloudWatch logs.

Comment: What shows when working with larger files? The logs should at least show that the Lambda function started and ended, together with the duration. Or are you saying that the function never even starts (according to the logs)? You might want to add more debug lines to understand what is happening in the function.

Comment: @JohnRotenstein it actually does not show anything. I have tried and waited for 15 mins, as I have set the timeout as such. All while constantly refreshing the page. But still nothing shows up on the CloudWatch logs.

Comment: If the file size is **under 15MB**, does CloudWatch Logs contain entries for `START`, `END` and `REPORT` for the function execution? And you are saying that these entries do NOT appear if the file is over 15MB? If so, this is an indication that the function was not invoked.

Comment: @JohnRotenstein I have edited the OP and provided a link to a screenshot of the log. When the uploaded file is 20mb, it does not show a new log.

Comment: Sometimes you need to go back one screen in CloudWatch Logs because it might have started a new Log Stream (normally caused by a code change, but can also be due to a new Lambda environment being provisioned). Every invocation of Lambda should generate log files. I suggest you get the logs working/found before looking at your code _within_ the function.

Comment: I have also tried invoking it again with a smaller file(5mb). A new log appeared. It seems that the function does not invoke when the file is larger than 15mb.

Comment: That is what you should solve first. Check in S3 that the trigger is configured to fire on "All object create events" rather than just Put/Post. It might be that multi-part uploads aren't triggering the Lambda function, and larger files are likely to use multi-part uploads.

Comment: It now works, thank you very much! But I have an additional question. Will this make the function trigger more invocation and will lead to costly use of the AWS Lambda? I am planning on using this method for auto-downloading of numerous files on a daily basis. Maybe a few thousand files per day.

Comment: What are you doing with the files after they are downloaded to the Lambda `/tmp/` directory?

Comment: I will upload them to ftp server using the **basic-ftp** library of **NodeJS**

Comment: It seems that your Lambda function is triggered by an object being created in an S3 bucket. It then downloads that file to `/tmp/` (FYI, you can do this without chunking it) and then it uploads that file to an FTP server. The Lambda function will only trigger once per file -- the fact that it is a multi-part upload that triggers the function won't make it trigger more often. Just make sure you delete the temporary file after uploading, otherwise the `/tmp/` disk space will fill up (or, always save it with the same name so that it is overwritten next time).

Comment: It works fine even without the chunking! Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It would appear that your AWS Lambda function is **not being triggered for files over 15 MB**.

Check the setting of your trigger and make sure it is configured for `All object create events`:

[image: S3 Event trigger]

This will include the **Multipart upload completed** option, which will trigger when a multi-part upload completes. This is typically used for large files, so it sounds like it might be the cause of the Lambda function not being invoked for larger files.